# Is there a way to unpickle data pickled by another program in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, pickle

I'm setting up an app-engine on Google Cloud Platform. I would like to get information contains in a particular file in a bucket in Storage.

This particular file is a binary one and has ".gst" for extension and it contains a python dictionary. It is available in "/bucket_name/dir_name/sub_dir_name/binary_file.gst"

I have already try some basics things like this :

```py
with cloudstorage.open(file_path) as cloudstorage_file:
    contents = pickle.load(cloudstorage_file)
```

or this

```py
with cloudstorage.open(file_path) as cloudstorage_file:
    contents = cloudstorage_file.read()
```

It doesn't work, and i don't know the right way to do this, so every help will be appreciate. I hope I've made it clear enough to get help.

Comment: I commented a solution below, but what’s the traceback for the pickle.load solution above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pickle can only deserialize objects if every module can be accessed from the same import path, so it is never a good idea to use pickle between different applications. If the file was generated from AppEngine, then it should work correctly.

Also, even with the same classes, if the other application was running on python 3, the default pickle protocol is not compatible with python 2.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you're trying to download and unpickle a file you have stored in a Cloud Storage Bucket.

You can download objects (no matter what file extension or type of file) using the [Python Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-code_sample)

After downloading it to a file, you could unpickle it like you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about with GAE, but you can use the Google Cloud Client Libraries:

```
#pip install google-cloud-storage

import pickle

from google.cloud import storage

blob_name = "dir_name/sub_dir_name/binary_file.gst"
blob = storage.Client(project=project_name).get_bucket(bucket_name).blob(blob_name)
contents = pickle.loads(blob.download_as_string())
```

Note that GCS doesn't actually have "folders" so everything that isn't the project_name or bucket_name is the blob_name in this example.